# Why does 오다 turn into 와요?

Tags: grammar

Sorry if it's a stupid question, I've picked up the Talk To Me In Korean Real Life Conversations E-Book as previously advised in my first question on here. There could just be several grammatical rules that I simply haven't learned about yet.

I understand that :

아요 - If the verb stem’s last vowel is ㅏ or ㅗ you add 아요.

어요 - If the verb stem’s last vowel not ㅏ or ㅗ you add 어요.

여요 - Add this to the verb stem that ends with 하.

But why does the 오 suddenly get a whole new vowel added to it?

Thanks to anyone who spends the time to help me on this :)

Comment: It first turns into 오아요, but people use 와요 *only*, which is the contraction of 오아요. *No one* uses 오아요 in real life, so Standard Korean does *not* allow the form 오아요. You should take it as an *exception.*

Answer (score 2):

> If the verb stem’s last vowel is ㅏ or ㅗ you add 아요

So, to 오 we would add 아요 = 오아요.

But remember that at the beginning of a character, ㅇ represents no sound - a 'null', if you like. So it makes perfect sense to remove that ㅇ in the middle...

오아요 = "오ㅏ요" = 와요